# PhpStorm 'Find Usages' Support for SPL PSR-0 class autoloading

Tags: ide, phpstorm, spl-autoload-register

In PhpStorm, I have no results when using the 'Find Usages' feature on my classes that use PSR-0 SPL autoloading. You do this by: selecting a file from the project project, right click, then find usages The shortcut is Alt + F7, and you can find usages in the editor view by Alt + f7 on the class declaration.

[image: using find usages feature on a class]

Here is the code:

```
spl_autoload_register(
    function ($class) {

    if (!strstr($class, "PHPExcel")) {
        include (__DIR__ . '/../classes/' . $class . '.php');
    }
});
```

'Find Usages' will not find any of these classes that in are included in this `spl_autoload_register` method in use, when they are used in the project.

[image: no usages found]

However, the 'Find Usages' feature does find results for classes instantiated with the `new` keyword and linked assets like CSS and JS, including the 'classes' directory.

[image: find usages working for a directory]

How can I add 'find usages' support for classes autoloaded with the spl_autoload_register method? I want to have search results returned showing the usages of the classes.

Comment: ?? Please clarify your issue (illustrate with some screenshots or something). WHat kind of support you want to have? Right now I do not understand how "Find Usages" is linked to your SPL autoloading code.

Comment: OK .. you have used "Find Usages" on file -- it did not found anything; Then you did it for `classes` folder -- it found where that folder was referenced. If you want to find **usage of specific class** .. then invoke "Find Usages" on that **class** (and not a file) -- place caret on class name in class definition and use that action. SPL autoloadign has no relation to that ... as IDE searches for usages in whole project regardless include/require directives.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realise right-click in the project view searched files only. Going into the file, right click the class declarition and then 'find usages' worked.